# regular expression to remove angular brackets

Tags: regex

i have text that goes like this:

```
WHERE Y_W_N IN  (<er,0>,<ER,-52>,<er,-1>) AND cat IN ('something sales','movies')
```

I'm trying to replace the `<v,v>`   with something like '1'
So in the case above, after the replacement I would get:

```
WHERE Y_W_N IN  ('1','1','1') AND cat IN ('something sales','movies')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
<[^,]*,[^,]*>
```

Replacement string:

```
'1'
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/9)

`[^,]*` matches any character but not of comma zero or more times.

Comment: What's the expected output for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<[^>]*>
```

Try this simple regex.Replace by `'1'`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/10

`[^>]*` will capture upto `>`

Comment: It will leave the last '>' out though. That's not what I want.

Comment: In the nested ones it will. For instance: <fw,<wy,0>>    Here the last '>' will be left out.